# Yocto, install Numpy

Tags: python, linux, gcc, numpy, yocto

I am really struggling on installing numpy in my :
`3.8.11-yocto-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 13 06:46:56 PDT 2014 i686 GNU/Linux` system.

I apologize but I am very newbie. So I download numpy from [here](http://www.numpy.org/), and did `python setup.py install` and it gives me error that `gfortran` and linear-algrebra library was not found.

My gcc version is 4.7.2, and currently, I don't have internet access in my Linux machine. I tried to use `dpkg` and it says command not found.

You might question how do I install the gcc? I install them by running `rpm` one and one and install those files:

```
ibusb-1.0-0-1.0.9-r1.i586.rpm
libmpfr4-3.1.1-r0.i586.rpm
libmpc2-0.8.2-r1.i586.rpm
binutils-2.23.1-r3.i586.rpm
gcc-4.7.2-r20.i586.rpm
gcc-symlinks-4.7.2-r20.i586.rpm
binutils-symlinks-2.23.1-r3.i586.rpm
eglibc-extra-nss-2.17-r3.i586.rpm
libcidn1-2.17-r3.i586.rpm
libc6-dev-2.17-r3.i586.rpm
libgcc-s-dev-4.7.2-r20.i586.rpm
libusb-1.0-dev-1.0.9-r1.i586.rpm
linux-libc-headers-dev-3.8-r0.i586.rpm
```

I spent my last few days investigating [installing gfortran](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries) and I have a hard time following and understand what is going on. Could I download one of the rpm here [gfortran rpm](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc-gfortran), and install it using rpm? If so, could I also install Numpy by install one of those [python rpm from here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=python-numpy)?

My current Python version is 2.7.3

PS: If I try my best to make internet access available to my Linux system, is there any one line command that could install Numpy for me?

eg, in Ubuntu, you could just do `sudo apt-get install Python-Numpy`.

Is there anything similiar for Yocto?

Comment: Did you read this link http://www.scipy.org/install.html. I think it is straight forward enough. I recommend to install virtualenv and try to do whatever you want over there.

Comment: Yes, I tried to look at it. I guess my option is to install from binary. Which leads back to the problem of not having gfortran+lapack, which are the dependency of the Numpy

Comment: No, yocto does not have a public repository to run commands like `apt-get install packagename`. You *might* have luck that one or another one works if the platform is the same, but there is *no* guarantee for this. I didn't have success to find any of these packages on http://layers.openembedded.org/ either.  What do you use this Yocto image for? Is yocto the right way for you on x86?

Comment: Did you try to compile the libgfortran package that seems part of the gcc recipe bundle (under poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc)?

Comment: Try installing one of the binary distributions linked to at http://scipy.org/install.html -- for example Anaconda. Shouldn't need gfortran or lapack, as they are bundled with it.

Comment: @pv. Since I have already have python-2.7.3 installed in my linux system, could I download http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html, and do `conda install numpy`?

Comment: @volker, I use Yocto because I have a Router (Cisco Grid Router 1000 Series) that runs on this as a virtual machine. I dont know how to compile libgfortran package

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Yocto has packages for [libgfortran](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=fortran) and [python-numpy](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=numpy). If you're using Yocto, you should be able to let it compile those packages for you via:

```
bitbake python-numpy libgfortran
```

The rpm packages should then be located in your `tmp/deploy/rpm/<arch>/` directory.

Comment: If gfortran is a dependency for numpy it will be automatically build